# Unable to load Google map

Tags: html, google-maps, jsp, bootstrap-modal

**Google Map** not loading.
only blank div is displaying

here my code snippet

```
<div id="map-container" class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>                                 
        function init_map() {
            var var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(35.710107,73.039610);                              
            var var_mapoptions = { center: var_location, zoom:17 };                              
            var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: var_location, map: var_map, title:"Test"});                              
            var var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"), var_mapoptions);                                 
            var_marker.setMap(var_map); 
        }                            
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);                              
    </script>
</div>
```

i think my logic is right. can anyone help me to figure it out what the problem is.

Thnx in advance. . . !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
    <div id="map-container" style="width: 100%; height:400px;"></div>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>                                 
        function init_map() {
            var var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(35.710107,73.039610);                              
            var var_mapoptions = { center: var_location, zoom:17 };                              
            var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: var_location, map: var_map, title:"Test"});                              
            var var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"), var_mapoptions);                                 
            var_marker.setMap(var_map); 
        }                            
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);                              
    </script>
</div>
```

You need to create another div for the map container and add the width & height for this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need an API Key, which you don't seem to have.

then basically just follow the google maps api tutorial, like you seem to have sorta been doing.

```
<style>
  #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
  }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)

Comment: because i don't have to change much in my previous code as compare to your answer.

Comment: your answer is also correct. but the other one is best in my case.